# Remove the shortened URL from the Post-Ban-Message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, post-ban

The message informing users about the [post ban carries a shortened URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this):

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

[image: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See ... to learn more.]

Can it please be replaced with a *real* link?

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. [See the FAQ page to learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this).

Comment: Yeah, this is bizarre. I'm constantly admonishing users for posting obfuscated URLs like this. I like to know what exactly I'm being linked to before I click.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Same thing here...I'm very surprised by this.

Comment: is it possible to get an actual picture of this? I'm also amazed and thought this was a joke when first reading the linked question.

Comment: @tombull89: That's a tough one, I wouldn't know how. But Grace Note said that it was there, though.

Comment: There's a link to the image in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/down-votes-should-not-have-any-side-effect-on-meta). I added a cropped version to your question, since some people remain unconvinced.

Comment: @tombull It's been consistently the same link on every report that I've seen turn up on the mod chat for this (there are 3 including the latest one, excluding the one Cody Gray just linked). As such, I figured it was reasonable to assume that it was indeed a shortened URL without waiting for visual proof. Also, I'm in favour of changing it, or at the very least making it clearer what it's linking to.

Comment: @Grace @Cody, I wasn't doubting you at all, I just thought it would be interesting to have a picture.

Comment: [url] describes questions that are about URLs themselves - from [stale URLs in questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89482/should-so-check-for-stale-404-urls) to [big URLs generated by the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87344/stack-exchange-user-page-url-is-frightening) just to take the first couple off the top of the list. This question is about a shortened URL employed by the system, so the tag seems appropriate. I'm not sure where you get that to be a Meta tag.

Comment: What the FAQ Page

Comment: @zod: What? What FAQ page?

Comment: @zod, FAQ = "Frequently Asked Questions".  The [link in the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) specifically addresses what's at issue here -- being banned from asking questions.

Comment: Related: [How about linking "Sorry we are no longer accepting questions …" message to faq?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87284/how-about-linking-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-message-to-faq)

Comment: @Jeff Do we get an explanation for "declined"? Is it simply "we don't like these people who get this message, so we don't care if they get an ugly message"?

Comment: @JeffAtwood perhaps now that we have s.tk it could be changed to be something like `s.tk/qban`?

Comment: Does this work better? [http://goo.gl/C1Kwu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi/86998#86998)

Comment: Ah, the link [has changed to use the help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183285/use-the-new-helpcenter-for-the-question-answer-ban-message/184182#184182). Not sure if it's still some `goo.gl` link or not. It surely [is not the old link anymore](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZKt6.png).

Answer (score -23, accepted):

The official reason is that we do not really care.

The users who get this message have **HEAVILY** abused the system, they failed repeatedly to provide any useful content on the site. They were given **multiple** chances to correct their ways and did not.

Should we invest any time in giving suspended users a [smoother](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100050/suspended-user-cannot-award-bounty/104355#104355) user experience?

I agree that url shortners are poor form, you do not teach bad with bad. However, we are hoping that by obfuscating the link some of the **absolute worst** offenders get confused, skip clicking on the link, and leave the site alone.

Comment: Or else they'll just ask on Meta until they get banned here too.

Comment: What actually happens is they get confused, skip clicking on the link, and post yet another "y i cant post?" question on meta

Comment: There's a simple way to [make sure that doesn't happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/were-no-longer-accepting-message-should-not-be-hosted-on-meta)

Comment: @waffles Random crazy idea: what do you think about replacing the goo.gl shortener with s.tk? Something catchy like s.tk/nomorequestions.

Comment: This is a ridiculous answer. Your sieve for filtering the absolute worst users from not so bad users is obscurity and poor UX?

Comment: @Asad: the page it links to is full of instructions on how to lift the ban. Instructions that, for most of the folks hitting it, are probably not very intuitive. If they can't follow the first instruction - clicking the weird short URL - there's probably not too much hope. I hate the short URL too, but to be perfectly honest I doubt it matters much.

Answer (score 23):

In June 2013 the link [has changed to use the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183285/use-the-new-helpcenter-for-the-question-answer-ban-message/184182#184182). Not sure if it's still some `goo.gl` link or not. It surely [is not the old link anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZKt6.png).

So the following is old:

One nice side-effect: we all got to see how often the thing was used. Just add the plus-character after the URL, just like with `bit.ly`: http://goo.gl/C1Kwu+ (But it seems one needs to be logged in to some Google account to see that.)

Until March 19 2012: 11,020 clicks since May 11 2011, oddly enough only 9,318 without any referrer. Hence: at least 1/5th of the clicks came from sites that actually had a clickable link, even a few from Facebook. (Many browsers also do not set a referrer when opening a clickable link in a new window.)

More non-scientific fun, all-time, all-sites `goo.gl` data, very roughly combined with the current SO visitor percentages from [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#countries):

```
══════Countries══════╤══Visits═
 India          3957 │  11.45% 
 United States  1908 │  32.19%
 United Kingdom  576 │   5.56%
 Canada          262 │   3.45%
 Germany         232 │   3.85%
 Pakistan        198 │   0.63%
 Australia       115 │   1.88%
 Singapore       108 │   0.66%
 China           103 │   2.05%
 Israel           81 │   0.70%

══════Browsers═══════
 Chrome         4494
 Firefox        4435
 IE             1094
 Safari          741
 Opera           204
 chromeframe      15
 Mobile Safari    14
 Ubuntu            5
 RockMelt          5
 Mobile            4

══════Platforms══════
 Windows        7829
 Macintosh      1886
 Other Unix     1141
 Ubuntu           88
 iPad             24
 Linux            18
 iPhone           13
 iPod             11
```

(Smart enough to install [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/), and still getting blocked...! Sorry for the tall overview; the previous [wide layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohN0Q.png) failed on [small screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567).)

Comment: Having the transparent stats available is interesting, I am sure  they gave a real link they could get the same stats from their weblogs or Google Analytics.

Comment: Sure, @Zoredache, but then *we* could not see them. :-) (But of course, that's hardly a reason to use the non-clickable `goo.gl` URL.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I updated with the latest stats from both Google and Quantcast. France dropped off the list, being replaced with Australia, but everything else pretty much continued the same trends from a year ago.

Comment: Singapore 108? :/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Er, *what* doesn't work anymore, @lunboks? Both [the Google stats](http://goo.gl/#analytics/goo.gl/C1Kwu/day) and [the Quantcast stats](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!traffic) look fine to me.

Comment: @Arjan I meant the goo.gl stats, but never mind. I was just not logged in, so I got redirected to http://goo.gl/.

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right @lunboks, on needs to be logged in to Google to see those stats. (Even though when logged in, one still sees a "signin" link on the overview.) Not too nice.

Comment: Hmmm, @Brad and all, it seems [the URL must have changed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UZKt6.png)? Ah, [indeed it did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183285/use-the-new-helpcenter-for-the-question-answer-ban-message/184182#184182).

Answer (score 21):

Yes! I understand that no one wants to read the full link `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998`, but actually `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86998` works fine as well (abusing the short-link feature for questions which also works for answers, though it's not officially supported) and indicates that it's a meta.SO question instead of some obfuscated short-URL

Comment: My question is still: Why not add a *real* link?

Comment: @Bobby: maybe this is some subtle "we assume you behaved bad so now we punish you by braking our own rules for you" psychology stuff? a direct link would of course be best, but for consistency with e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error I suggested the URL

Comment: @Straitjacket, Tim has a good point [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103230/what-can-we-do-to-prevent-people-from-posting-their-coding-questions-on-meta/103233#comment-263508): *I'm in favor of just putting the text that is linked into the page that is displayed when someone hits the ban. Bringing them to MSO really doesn't accomplish anything, because the ban can't be lifted.*

Answer (score 12):

The link on the [post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) page has changed to an actual link to a full URL.

---

From the [Super User ask page](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

[image: Screenshot of new post-ban page]

Comment: Did you get question-banned on Super User just so you could demonstrate this?

Comment: That would be dedication, but no.  I just came across this post during my own...issues, and saw it needed updating, both on needing different tags for the question and a more up-to-date answer

Comment: I saw the edit to the question, but like you said, you can't actually change the status. If you want to get that changed, you should flag for moderator attention. Use the "other" option to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, done.