# How can I access my stackoverflow account?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

When I click on Ask Question I get this message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting
>   questions from this account. See
>   http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

how i reactivate my account? so that i can ask question again?

Comment: @squillman I'm not sure "how to access this facility" is what he meant; that doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Michael Facility = feature.  I just replaced excess with access there.  Made sense to me.

Comment: @squillman I think you were right, but less for the equation there and more for the "access this facility" → "access/use Stack Overflow" → "ask questions" progression.

Comment: @Grace Yeah, probably.  He changed it anyway.

Answer (score 10):

[image: See goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more]

Comment: Sweet, freehand arrow and circle +1.

Comment: Wait, you mean to tell me that we *still* haven't [fixed the obfuscated URL in the help text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91459/remove-the-shortened-url-from-the-post-ban-message)?