# Suspended user cannot award bounty

Tags: support, status-declined, bounties, account-suspension

I asked a question on Stack Overflow: [Refactoring and creating separate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606967/refactoring-and-creating-seperate-methods).

I want to award my bounty to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606967/refactoring-and-creating-seperate-methods/6824211#6824211) by user [NetMage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257038/netmage)

However, my Stack Overflow account is suspended recently for 7 days, and the suspension still has 5 more days to end. And I know I can't vote, ask, answer, or comment as pointed on [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) by [Mr.Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) with the sentence below.

> You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

I couldn't find anything about not being able to *accept an answer* or *award bounty* so I tried to accept the mentioned answer above and award my bounty to it and I got a

> Suspended users cannot vote

rejection which can be seen below with a screenshot.

[image: Suspended users cannot vote screenshot]

I know this

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted
> answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will
> be awarded half the bounty amount.

from [the Bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

None of the answers given to my question is upvoted and the answer I mentioned is not the oldest one after the bounty started so it won't be awarded by community.

What can I do? (except being a good guy and not get suspended :))

Comment: I didn't request any feature or anything why did you add a status-declined tag to this question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my opinion, it's too much of a corner case to address it in code. Perhaps someone on the team can reset the bounty expiration to after the suspension expires.  I'd send a note to team@stackoverflow.com (perhaps pointing them to this question), though I suspect they'll see it here anyway.

Comment: yes, that could work I guess and I am also ok with somebody from SO team accepting that answer and awarding the bounty if it is possible.Thank you Mr.tvanfosson.

Answer (score 14):

We have said this before, I will say it again.

We do not intend to put any extra effort supporting outlier users that have abused the system.  Consider being unable to assign a bounty part of your "punishment".

Comment: Aren't you just punishing the people who answered the question, before they even knew they cannot get the bounty?

Comment: @Kobi, the odds this would happen are so low that I do not care to fix it. If we allow suspended users a certain class of actions, we are not suspending them

Comment: this answer does not make sense because the person being most punished is not the "abuser", but the answerer, so regardless of whether you think it should be fixed, which is another issue, this answer is wrong.