# Can suspended users post comments? Get notifications? What happens to their reputation?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I have some questions about a suspended user's earning and activity.

1. Can suspended users get reputation back after the suspension period?
2. If a user is suspended for 7 days and he/she earns reputation during this period. Then will it be calculated after completing suspension period?
3. If a suspended user has awarded a bounty to other user and the awarded bounty marked as illegal. Then will that bounty rolled back to their account?
4. Can suspended users get any alert from comments or chat room using @username method?
5. Can suspended users post comments on his/her question/answer? If another user replies or ask a question on suspended user's post. Then, can a suspended user give response back?

Answer (score 5):

1. > Can suspended users get reputation back after the suspension period?

   Yes. Well, at least that much that wasn't gained fraudulently. (Reputation is re-calculated when suspension is over.)
2. > If a user is suspended for 7 days and he/she earns reputation during this period. Then will it be calculated after completing suspension period?

   Yes.
3. > If a suspended user has awarded a bounty to other user and the awarded bounty marked as illegal. Then will that bounty rolled back to their account?

   Varies on a case-by-case basis.
4. > Can suspended users get any alert from comments or chat room using @username method?

   Yes, suspension does not affect received notifications.
5. > Can suspended users post comments on his/her question/answer? If another user replies or ask a question on suspended user's post. Then, can a suspended user give response back?

   No. Suspended users cannot post/submit anything.

Comment: Well yeah, except mod message replies maybe, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BoltClok'saUnicorn. Suppose user has posted a answer on someone's question then user has suspended for some period. In that period Questioner ask a query related to that answer. So, should suspended user be allowed to give reply back.

Comment: @danta: Uh, no. I'm not sure why you would think so. It's a suspension.

Comment: I feel about other users who has to wait for reply from suspended user until suspension period not over.

Answer (score 1):

Answers as follows,

1. > Can suspended user get reputation back after suspension period?

   User get re-calculated reputation once the suspension period is finished. Meaning all the false vote done & get will be removed.
2. > If user has suspended for 7 days and he/she get reputation during this period. Then will it be calculated after completing suspension period?

   During suspension if any of the posts get upvote ( legally ) then user surely gets that reputation points. Also if any un-accepted answer gets accepted then also he receives +15 for the same.
3. > If suspended user has awarded a bounty to other user and the awarded bounty marked as illegal. Then will that bounty rolled back to their account?

   [Shog9 has already replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224486/252811)
4. > Can suspended user get any alert from comment or chat room using @username method?

   Yes, user can receive the comments but can not reply it.
5. > Can suspended user give comment on his/her question/answer? If another user replies or ask a question on suspended user's post. Then, can suspended user give response back?

   Suspended user can not give comment. He can only reply to Moderator's message.

For more information please read this [Stackoverflow's blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: *Meaning all the false vote done & get will be removed.* Not all suspensions are the result of voting fraud.

Comment: @Bart Right, but when moderator removed the sock-puppoets account then all the votese from those accounts get vanish, that's what I wanted to say.