# Can a user accept answers during a suspension?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, users, account-suspension

If I had posted a question that got an answer, and if I hadn't accepted the answer before I got suspended, would I be able to mark the answer as accepted during the time that I was suspended from the site?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100050/suspended-user-cannot-award-bounty?rq=1 - apparently no. Should probably be added to the FAQ though, it's not entirely evident that accepts and bounty awards are votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No.

If you try to accept (or, similarly, unaccept) an answer to one of your question on a site where you're suspended, you get an error message:

[image]

Comment: To those who are wondering why it's done this way: Suspensions are often used to stop people from mucking with the reputation system, and if people could screw with their answer acceptances, that use wouldn't work very well. (When you're suspended, you're supposed to be _just_ an observer.)

Comment: It's like this because, as that screenshot indicates, accepting is a type of voting, which is disabled for suspended users.