# Introduce share via barcode

Tags: feature-request

Use case: this evening I go outside and haven't finished reading some of SO questions I started some time before. I will spend some time on my way and will have my mobile, but I can't get all the questions opened on my desktop quickly reopened on smartphone: I have to retype "short" URIs.

What if to add a barcode which I could read via mobile and open in a browser?

Comment: We should get some QR codes as well. Hell, QR codes are the *new* barcodes.

Comment: I actually "abuse" favorites for that exact purpose

Comment: And I thought it's getting harder everyday to find a browser that does *not* want to sync desktop and mobile sessions for me... (Hint: Chrome to the rescue?)

Comment: Just found a proposal as QR code. So this question could be considered as duplicate of [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101949/would-anyone-be-interested-in-qr-codes-for-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101949/would-anyone-be-interested-in-qr-codes-for-questions).

Comment: I like browser synch... what about that?