# Stop missing upvotes by adding QR codes which can be scanned by the app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, voting, participation

I often use Stack Exchange without having signed in on it (thru my company's office for example). I often cannot upvote a good question, because I'm not logged or the proxy won't allow me to log.

I always have to search for the question I want to upvote in my mobile app, and this is an annoying manual process. Because of this, I only upvote one out of ten answers that I wanted to upvote.

I wonder how many hundreds of thousands of people don't upvote simply because logging in takes too much time or because they are on a proxy at work.

It would be great if we could reverse this waste of votes by allowing the Stack Exchange app (which is always logged in) to take a screenshot of a question and automatically navigate to it from the app (a bar code as we see in WhatsApp web), so that the voting can be sped up.

Comment: What app? iOS or android? Not that it matters, both are frozen and would likely be removed at some point, but we can still suggest new idea, even if it's waste of time in the long range.

Comment: I use android. This is my only way to vote. If they remove it, I wonder how many people will stop voting

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101949/would-anyone-be-interested-in-qr-codes-for-questions.

Comment: Not as many as you think since not many are using the app, otherwise they wouldn't kill it. Anyway... I think it's interesting idea, but my advise is don't build your hopes for this to be done. My tip for quick upvote is send yourself the question/answer link via email or even Facebook (there's "share" link below each post), open the email/facebook on your mobile phone and follow the link.

Comment: Android has some OCR support. One could build an app that scans a question title, then sends an Intent to SE app. Still need to figure out if the SE app can automatically navigate to a given question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth it can; I think it's just the URL of the question. In the now-to-be-phased out mobile version of the site, there is a banner worded like 'check this question in our mobile app' (I've dismissed those once and don't see them.) That took you directly to the question in the mobile app (at least on iOS).

Comment: Would using the browser on your phone be a workaround? I've never used the app, but the site seems to work ok in a mobile browser.