# Statistics on number of users being post-banned?

Tags: support, users, post-ban, statistics

I am interested in statistics on number of users getting [post ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/189976), for different SX sites. Is such information available? Is it possible to get such information from the Data Explorer? (Then it would be enough to show me how, I can make the SQL request myself.)

Answer (score 9):

While we don't have public statistics for the number of users who have been question-banned, we do have access to the number of clicks the "we are no longer accepting questions from your account, see here" link has received. As [pointed out by Arjan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102973/135615), you can use the http://goo.gl/C1Kwu+ link to access stats about how many times that shortened link has been used. It sounds like you do need to be logged in to Google services to see those stats, though.

As of today (Feb 9, 2013), that link has been clicked 36000 times. 12200 of those clicks came from India, 5870 from the U.S., and 1865 from the U.K, with the rest of the world well behind those countries. I believe the same link is used for all Stack Exchange sites, so you can't separate out where the bans were taking place, but I imagine Stack Overflow accounts for the vast majority of those clicks.

Comment: Wow... in other words, the language barrier is a HUGE problem.

Comment: Not necessarily @mystical, it _could_ indicate that Indian users are more conscientious about checking and re-checking how to overturn their ban...

Comment: @Mysticial also, India has ~3x the number of humans that the U.S. does, so their click-per-capita rate is actually behind the U.S.  OTOH, the U.S. has ~x5 the number of humans in the U.K., so the U.K. clicks-per-capita is like 60% more than the U.S.  If there is a language barrier, as you suggest, it's that the English don't understand English.

Answer (score 6):

No, such information is not (publicly) available.

Comment: Actually, Shog posted this information a while back.

Comment: @Mysticial I know, and he also gave me some stats when [I asked for them](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users). That doesn't really count as "publicly available" though.

Comment: Not just that, I don't think SE actually tracks it (at least not in an excessively fancy way). Shog probably had to do an internal query to get this information.

Comment: That's a pity. It would be interesting to know how this number differs from site to site.

Comment: @tohecz Yeah, I'd really like to take a peak at those numbers myself, but right now all you can do is ask a SE employee to dig in the database. And of course they won't do it without good reason.