# Modrewrite for the profile url's?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, vanity-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature request: vanity URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49462/feature-request-vanity-urls)

Instead of

https://stackoverflow.com/users/542109/hcp

I would rather have something easier to remember like

https://stackoverflow.com/HCP_NL_AMS

point to my profile. (NL for the netherlands, AMS for amsterdam)

Is that possible someway or another ?

Comment: I really don't understand why `HCP_NL_AMS` is better...

Comment: Even if HCP_NL_AMS was objectively better, one could readily argue that `Adam_Davis_Ann_Arbor_MI` is worse than `users/2915/adam-davis` or even the shorthand `users/2915`. I don't see any particular value in having yet another way to refer to a user. I think the suggestion to [use a URL shortening service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87344/stack-exchange-user-page-url-is-frightening/88706#88706) is probably the best way to go about personalizing one's links.

Comment: @Cody Gray as it is easier to remember HCP then 542109

Answer (score 2):

User names are not unique AFAIK. So it could be ambiguous, even with the country or town. (Try typing John in the user search)

By the way, this requires the maintenance of a mapping tables for the webserver[1] (that would not be nice regarding the performances), as well as at least one true redirection (when you try to access https://stackoverflow.com/users/542109/hcp, you need a 301 redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/HCP_NL_AMS)

I know the mechanism exists on Career 2.0, but the objectives are not the same, because you use your real name on it (normally). So ambiguousness is fairly rare. On SO, you would just add pain to the users trying to catch an unmatched name. We don't want to see "John14352432-2" or "John_", "John___" and other derivation of this if it can be avoided.

[1] which is probably IIS since SE runs on .NET framework... so not mod_rewrite exactly.